# URL parameters, the back button and duplicate content

Tags: seo, back-button, robots.txt

I have an e-commerce site. For the T-shirts page I want the only URL indexed by search engines to be

```
mysite/items/t-shirts/
```

But there are filters on the page so a user can filter by size, colour, material etc.

I thought about keeping the URL to always display as

```
mysite/items/t-shirts/
```

regardless of which filters are chosen so that search engines don't index pages like:

```
mysite/items/t-shirts/?colour=red
mysite/items/t-shirts/?colour=red&size=xl
mysite/items/t-shirts/?colour=red&size=xl&material=cotton
```

but this breaks the back button.

So I'm thinking of keeping the URL parameters so the back button can be used and to prevent search engines from indexing urls with parameters I'll put the following in the robots.txt file:

```
User-agent: *
# Block crawlers from storing pages with parameters
Disallow: /*/*?
```

Is this the best approach or are there better alternatives?

Comment: IMO you should keep the URL parameters, this is very common practise, and if SEO is done correctly your query params shouldn't count as different pages to the base page.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't about programming. You may have better luck asking on the [Webmasters.SE] site.